# Проверка строки (полного пути) регулярным выражением на недопустимые символы в именах файлов (папок) WIndows

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

> Заданное имя документа не является допустимым именем файла. Имена файлов не должны содержать следующие символы:
>
> - Звездочка (`*`)
> - Вертикальная черта (`|`)
> - Двоеточие (`:`)
> - Двойные кавычки (`"`).
> - Меньше (`<`)
> - Больше (`>`)
> - Вопросительный знак (`?`)
> - Косая черта (`/`)
> - Обратную косую черту (`\`) я проверю как существование каталога.

Помогите пожалуйста составить регулярное выражение на проверку вхождения вышеперечисленных символов в строку(путь от диска к папке), может у кого-нибудь есть уже готовое решение, подобный пример? Мне нужно проверить на корректность введённый путь (Проверка существования каталога не подходит так как выдаёт исключение если ввести недопустимый символ).

Нужно отловить все недопустимые символы при вводе пользователем пути. Например если я буду проверять путь на существование каталогов то мне выдаст исключение из-за недопустимого символа, поэтому мне нужно отловить все недопустимые символы. И непонятно, выдаст ли мне исключение если я введу такой путь `C:\folder\fol:der`, на символы `<`, `>` и другие я получал исключения. Нужно быть уверенным что какой бы путь пользователь не ввёл программа не завершит работу а отловит ошибку и продолжит ввод пути.

Проверяю путь вот так:

```
Path Path;

if (Files.exists(Path))
    out.println("    Путь введён\n");
else
    out.println("    Ошибка");
```

Если в переменной недопустимый символ то выдаётся исключения:

> Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal
>   char < ? > at index 0: ?
>   Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal
>   char <<> at index 0: <

Comment: Гугл в помощь: [regex match windows filename](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6804755/3347171).

Comment: @GreyGoblin Отвечайте на вопрос нажав на соответствующую кнопку ;)

Comment: Не понятно, как вы хотите исключать бэкслэш  из допустимых символов, если это разделитель пути в win. приведите в вопросе, примеры некорректного, согласно вашей логике, пути и правильного пути. сейчас вопрос непонятен и, мне кажется, минусы ставят по этой причине

Comment: @while1pass Я подправил, Вы правы. Обратную черту я проверю как существование каталога.

Comment: и все равно не понятно чего вы хотите, приведите примеры. двоеточие тоже входит в путь win-системах. например, C:\multitran\PUH\history.txt

Comment: @while1pass Нужно отловить все недопустимые символы при вводе пользователем пути. Например если я буду проверять путь на существование каталогов то мне выдаст исключение из-за недопустимого символа, поэтому мне нужно отловить все недопустимые символы.

Comment: @while1pass Отредактировал.

Comment: [Ссылка раз](https://www.codeproject.com/tips/216238/regular-expression-to-validate-file-path-and-exten), [ссылка два](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/120002/windows-filepath-and-filename-validation).

Comment: @pinkTux Я под файлами пути подразумевал только папки, поэтому немного отредактировал вопрос, и наверно мой ответ наиболее подходит.

Comment: @while1pass Пример: D:\folder, D:\folder:\fol:der\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ввод недопустимых символов и отсутствие каталога отловил следующим образом:

```
String WAY;

public void WAY() {

    do {
        out.print("  Vvedite adres programm\n");

        boolean WHILE = true;

        out.print("      ");

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        WAY = in.next();

        try {
            Path PATH = Paths.get(WAY);

            if(Files.exists(PATH)) {
                out.print("        Adres programm vvedon\n");

                WHILE = false;
            }
            else
                out.print("        Oshibka\n");
        }
        catch (InvalidPathException e) {
            out.print("        Oshibka\n");
        }

    }
    while(WHILE);

}
```

Comment: Где же тут регулярные выражения, которые вы затребовали для решения этой задачи? )

Comment: @Kromster Где же вы были раньше? )

Answer (score 3):

Могу предположить, что что-то такое:

```
[a-z]:([\\/]?([^*|\\/:"<>]*))*
```

Comment: Что-то-то? Это сработает? Как-то неуверено :)

Comment: @ELe, должно сработать, но я не проверял :)

Comment: `Readme.txt`, `Test\Readme.txt`, `Test\Readme.txt`, `\\Server\Test\Readme.txt`

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Что это?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, просили проверять полный путь. UNC - да, не рассчитывал на него. Но для нормальных путей с файлом должно бы работать.

Answer (score 2):

Если мы говорим только об **имени** файла, то так

```
[^\*\|\\\:\"<>\?\/]
```

Если же нужно проверять полный путь, то все не так просто

Comment: Спасибо, но нужно проверять полный путь.